# Как мы нашли y и x?

Tags: геометрия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу спрограмировать прямую.  но не пойму как мы с определения получили y и x?? И как это разрешить уравнение относительно y?

Comment: Можно выразить уравнение через y: `y=-(ax+c)/b` - и, подставляя значения x, вычислять точки, принадлежащие заданной прямой

Comment: Да но как тут вывели что y = - (a/b) , и  x = -(c / b)??

Comment: Это только одно из возможных решений. Как его вывели пока не важно.

Comment: Здесь опечатка. Должно быть так, как я написал выше